# Scrapy start_urls request returns 503, how to catch it?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Currently I have written very simple spider, as follows

```
class QASpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my-spider";
    handle_httpstatus_list = [400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,426,428,429,431,451,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,510,511];
    allowed_domains = ["local-02"];
    start_urls = preview_starting_urls;
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=True)]

    def parse_url(self, response):
        # Some operations
```

In `preview_starting_urls` there are urls I intend to start crawling from and the spider works just fine, as long as I get response code 200 from the starting URL. But when there is 503 on any of the starting URLS, `parse_url` method is not called.

I figured that this behavior occurs because scrapy does not call my own callbacks if request to start_url(s) fails, so I tried defining default callback method:

```
def parse(self, response)
    parse_url(response);
```

But this resulted in my spider crawling only start_urls (and in sending some other scrapy requests, like for robots.txt and similar) and nothing else.

The point is that when I do not define default callback `parse/2` method, I do not get to process any of the start_urls in case they return request code different than 200. If I define `parse/2` method as written above, spider does not crawl all the urls, as it would crawl without `parse/2` defined.

How do I force scrapy to call my callback even for `start_urls` that return response different from 200?

**Edit**: Also I am open for suggestions on how to fill `handle_httpstatus_list` with values elegantly.

Comment: If by populating the `handle_httpstatus_list` elegantly you mean some shorter expression, try using `range` and list concatenation.

Comment: @TomášLinhart Yes, that is what I meant, something similar to Haskell ranges, like `[300..599]`, but `list(range(300,600))` also does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To catch error in scrapy is pretty simple. Just create a new Function that needs to be called when an *Error* occurs, and pass this as the default function to be called for errors when doing a `Request`. As you want to do it for the starting URLs, you will have to call the `start_request` function manually to access the `yield Request` call

```
#replace start_urls 
#error_function() called when error occurs
def start_requests(self):
    urls = preview_starting_urls
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_url, errback=self.error_function)

def error_function(self,failure):
    self.logger.error(repr(failure))
    #write your error parse code
```

---

> [errback](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html?highlight=errback) (callable) – a function that will be called if any exception was raised while processing the request. This includes pages that failed with 404 HTTP errors and such. It receives a Twisted Failure instance as first parameter.

Comment: Alright, it looked promising, but it seems to ignore 'rules' now. I want it to start from the `preview_starting_urls` and to continue (as specified in `rules`, hopefully, by extracting links from the visited website and continue crawling them). Now it again only crawls few pages (does not log anything btw), and terminates.

Comment: Hmmmm. It works properly for my test spider. The problem would be due to `rules` and unfortunately I haven't tried them out as of yet and so can't comment on that yet. As for extracting links, you can do that manually in the `parse_url` function and then work on them, or integration of `rules` will ofcourse solve the problem. As for Logs, I can't do anything but guess as its code is not available, that the problem is due to not parsing of many of the URLs that should be obtained from the `rules`.